# Name for matrices with $M_{i,j} = M_{n-i+1, n-j+1}$ symmetry (eg. 2D autocorrelation)?

Tags: covariance, autocorrelation, terminology, spatial, image-processing

Covariance matrices are symmetric positive definite matrices. The 'Symmetric' part of this means that the strict upper elements are redundant with the strict lower elements, i.e $M_{i,j} = M_{j,i}$. Thus, a covariance matrix has $\frac{n*(n+1)}{2}$ non-repeated elements.

In the case of an autocovariance matrix for a 2D signal, the resulting matrix has different type of symmetry, with $M_{i,j} = M_{n-i+1, n-j+1}$. With this symmetry, for example, we have that $M_{i,i} = M_{n-i, n-i}$, so unlike covariance matrices we also have repeated diagonal elements, besides having redundant strict upper and strict lower triangular parts. This leads this class of matrices to have $\frac{n^2+1}{2}$ non-repeated elements (with  odd $n$).

I'm wondering if there's a name to describe the second type of matrices, or for the type of symmetry, so as to refer to the fact that they have $\frac{n^2+1}{2}$ non-repeated elements.